# For every month order has been made find the number of orders delivered on time

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, status

for every month order has been made, find the number of orders delivered on time .order the result by ascending order?

order table

```
ID  order_Date                  delivery_Date
 1   2018-03-12  07:0:00         2018-03-12  07:0:00
 2   2018-03-19  09:00:00         2018-03-19  09:12:00
 3   2018-02-15  09:00:00         2018-02-20  09:12:00
 4   2018-02-16  10:00:00         2018-02-16  10:30:00
```

status table

```
ID  order_Date                  delivery_Date               expeacted_delivery_time       status
 1   2018-03-12  07:0:00         2018-03-12  07:0:00         2018-03-12  07:30:00          intime
 2   2018-03-19  09:00:00         2018-03-19  09:12:00       2018-03-19  09:30:00           intime
 3   2018-02-15  09:00:00         2018-02-20  09:12:00       2018-02-15  09:30:00           late
 4   2018-02-16  10:00:00         2018-02-16  10:30:00       2018-02-16  11:00:00           intime
```

Sample Output

```
month   total
2018-03     2
2018-02     1
```

Comment: please let us know if you are still facing difficulties with this query.

Answer (score -1):

You can have your desired result with group by from status table.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_Date , "%Y %m") month,count(*) total from status
where status='intime'
group by DATE_FORMAT(order_Date , "%Y %m")
order by count(*) desc;
```

In your output result in descending order. So in query I have selected the result in descending order of total count.

To have the result in ascending order of date:

```
order by DATE_FORMAT(order_Date , "%Y %m");
```

To have the result in descending order of date:

```
order by DATE_FORMAT(order_Date , "%Y %m") desc;
```

To have the result in ascending order of total count:

```
order by count(*);
```